# Framework resource extraction failed. Could not find part of the path. AbstractionsStrings.resw

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, entity-framework-core

I want to run [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-tutorials-customer-database) by microsoft. But I gets error compile:

> Framework resource extraction failed. Could not find part of the path
>
> "C:\Users\Owl\Desktop\windows-tutorials-customer-database-master\windows-tutorials-customer-database-master\CustomerDatabaseTutorial.App\obj\x64\Debug\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions\en-US\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Properties.AbstractionsStrings.resw".   CustomerDatabaseTutorial.App

I did't anything. Just download and run. What's problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If open this example, Visual Studio shows dialog window with information about minimal SDK. I have clicked OK, but needed hyperlink "install". After downloaded new SDK version, the app was running without error compile.

Answer (score 4):

This because of longest file path, try to change short file path name
This issue get solved

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database/issues/19